# How to write a script in r that runs on file?

Tags: r

I have several Data frames that I would like to preform the same actions on them, such as sorting and remove duplicates, is there a way to preform the actions automatically using a script?
The DF is test:

```
1.DateTime=as.POSIXct(test $ TimeStamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
2.VehicleType = as.factor(test$VehicleType) 
3.UnitId = as.factor(test$UnitId) 
4.test $ TimeStamp = DateTime 
5.test$VehicleType= VehicleType 
6.test$UnitId=UnitId
7.test <- test [order(test$TimeStamp) , ]
```

After that I want to save the DF with the changes.

Is a script the right way to go? or maybe I should use a Function? I want to enter the file and make the script run on it.

Comment: You can read the multiple datasets in a list and may be wrap this as a function and apply on them. i.e. `files <- list.files()` assuming all the files are in the working directory.  `lst <- lapply(files, function(x) yourfunction(read.table(x, header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`  Then use `write.table` i.e. `lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) write.table(lst[[i]], file=files[i], ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your code to a function and call the function for all your files (I cleaned a bit of your code to save space, it still functions the same!):

```
clean <- function(testFile){
  testFile$TimeStamp <- as.POSIXct(testFile$TimeStamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
  testFile$VehicleType <- as.factor(testFile$VehicleType) 
  testFile$UnitId <- as.factor(testFile$UnitId) 

  #Further cleaning here if needed...
  #Lastly, return the clean file.

  return(testFile)
}

test <- clean(test)
test2 <- clean(test2)
#etc...
```

This works if you already have your files loaded into data frames ('test', 'test2' and so on). You could also add the data frames to a list and call the function for the whole list like @akrun says in his comment, it depends on how many files you are cleaning.